# Difference Between internetStatus and hostStatus

Tags: ios, ipad, connection

i want to check internet connection in my App. While doing that, i use following code. 
What is the difference between internetStatus and host status. Which should i use to check whether ipad has internet connection or not.

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            //self.internetActive = NO;
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            //self.hostActive = NO;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed"
                                                            message:@"No internet connection"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert setDelegate:self];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];


            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            //self.internetActive = YES;

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            //self.internetActive = YES;

            break;
        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            //self.hostActive = NO;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Failed"
                                                              message:@"No internet connection"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert setDelegate:self];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            //self.hostActive = YES;

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            //self.hostActive = YES;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to create hostReachable and internetReachable? Anyway, they are simply variable names.

Answer (score 1):

`internetStatus` or `hostStatus` just the instance name you can use any name for status. but specifically if you don't set the host then you can use `internetStatus` for internet access if it is reachable or not, by default apple checks for internet availability to the internet gateway or internet connection, in this case we don't know the hostname for checking the internet connectivity , however you can use `hostStatus` or any instance name for a particular host, you could set the random host yourself e.g [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and check if it is reachable. procedure is similar.

basically status is depending on your hostname which can be default or you can set it yourself like this;

```
hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.com"];
[hostReachable startNotifier];
```